# Service or started program by a service with administrative rights

Tags: windows, service, uac, rights

For updating our software we used a VB6 updating program, with update levels and different update sources. It copied the necessary files from the update sources to the local destination ( C:\program files\company\product).

VB6 programs can only run with a service helper (srvany or similar) as a service and don't have enough rights to change or add new files in the given folder. But even a .NET program has not the necessary rights to do it, only if you set the administrator credentials on the service.

If the client would not set the service with the administrator credentials, how can we use a service or a program called by a service to changes the files in the given folder, means that it has administrative rights.

MSI/MSP is not possible because of the given update levels (different users with different program and report versions).

We tried to call an external program from a C#.NET Service with elevation, but no way...
We checked out some tipps and tricks with manifest files or thought to make a COM object that could have administrative rights, but I think this is the wrong way.

Another possibility is to create a scheduled task by giving the 'hightest pivilege'. But does that work? If the task should run after login and different users could use this computer, you should define a task for each user... We don't know each login on the clients computer, because they change very often.

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 0):

To start something elevated, you need a service that runs as local system so that it has the required privileges to access Program Files. Yet service always runs, and takes memory.

You can create a scheduled task which will start after a certain period of time. I'm not sure, though, it's possible to run a task elevated without UAC confirmation.

Manifests should also allow you to start another application elevated.

---

Basically your updater does not need to be elevated: it can download the update files into `ProgramData` which is writable by each user. When download completes, it starts the installer requiring the administrative privileges.

Firefox uses auto-update mechanism: when it downloaded a newer version, it prompts for elevation to apply the update.

Apple Quicktime uses a scheduled task to start the updater. It presents interface where users can select what updates they want to install. It downloads the update files, prompts for elevation and then applies the updates.

If you do not want any user interaction, then service is the best bet.